# An elegant way in C# to separate a comma separated list of email addresses

Tags: c#

Looking on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451862/223742) there are various approaches to this problem, however the recommended solution for instance does not deal with **\"Last, First\" "** and the suggestion posted by richard in that post is missing the code to SetUpTextFieldParser()

I have the following list of email addresses as a string:

```
string str = "Last, First <name@domain.com>, name@domain.com, First Last <name@domain.com>, \"First Last\" <name@domain.com>, \"Last, First\" <name@domain.com>";
```

Current code does a:

```
str.Split(",");
```

which produces an incorrect list because of the comma in:

```
"Last, First"
```

Anyone got something elegant here to share so that I end up with an array of strings in the form:

```
Last, First <name@domain.com>
name@domain.com
First Last <name@domain.com>
"First Last" <name@domain.com>
"Last, First" <name@domain.com>
```

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

I ended up using Yacoub Massad's solution as it was simple (regular expressions would be hard to maintain in my dev group as not everyone understands them). Below is the code ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sn69pp)) with some additions and simplistic testing to make sure all was well:

- Trailing comma in case someone got careless
- Addition of (comment) email address formats from MSDN page

_

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Mail;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(v=vs.110).aspx
        //Some esoteric "comment" formats as well as a trailing comma in case someone did not tidy up
        string emails = "Last, First <name@domain.com>, name@domain.com, First Last <name@domain.com>, \"First Last\" <name@domain.com>, \"Last, First\" <name@domain.com>,  (comment)\"First, Last\"(comment)<(comment)joe(comment)@(comment)there.com(comment)>(comment),";
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        Console.WriteLine("LOOP");
        while (true)
        {
            int position_of_at = emails.IndexOf("@");
            if (position_of_at == -1)
            {
                break;
            }

            int position_of_comma = emails.IndexOf(",", position_of_at);
            if (position_of_comma == -1)
            {
                result.Add(emails);
                break;
            }

            string email = emails.Substring(0, position_of_comma);
            result.Add(email);
            emails = emails.Substring(position_of_comma + 1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("/LOOP");

        //Do some very basic validation of above code
        var i = 1;
        if (result.Count == 6)
            Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS: " + result.Count);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("FAILURE: " + result.Count);
        foreach (string emailAddress in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==== " + i.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(emailAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("/====");
            MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
            Console.WriteLine(mailAddress.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine("---- " + i.ToString());
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: split it on >, instead of , and remove the extra < ?

Comment: @SpaceSteak that wouldn't catch the second email address.

Comment: You (or anyone generating that) should have escaped character  supposed to be used as separator :)

Comment: I would suggest possibly writing a preparser to format your data in a consistent manner. Otherwise I don't see a simple way of doing it other than to create a list of rules to apply.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I have no control of how the data reaches me unfortunately ;-)

Comment: The linked answer a recommended one, it's just the answer accepted by whoever posted the question. As the highest voted answer says though, it *isn't* that simple. A regular expression may or may not work, because email addresses themselves can contain unexpected characters

Comment: @TheEdge Do you need the First and Last name from all those examples, or can we give you something that just extracts the email address?

Comment: @TheEdge: very unfortunate people generating that didn't take into account that comma could be present on data. Since that's a bug, can't you ask them to fix it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you compare the highest voted you will see that it is the same code as the accepted ;-)

Comment: @CBauer Unfortunately I need the names as well.

Comment: why don't you split it with space and check if the string in array contains @. and then if string contains < remove it?

Comment: The question is not meant for the answer. You can separate it and add your own solution as an answer to your own question instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List<string> ExtractEmails(string emails)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    while (true)
    {
        int position_of_at = emails.IndexOf("@");

        if (position_of_at == -1)
        {
            break;
        }

        int position_of_comma = emails.IndexOf(",", position_of_at);

        if (position_of_comma == -1)
        {
            result.Add(emails);
            break;
        }

        string email = emails.Substring(0, position_of_comma);

        result.Add(email);

        emails = emails.Substring(position_of_comma + 1);

    }

    return result;
}
```

It assumes that all emails are going to contain the `@` character.

It works by considering only the commas that appear after the `@` character as splitting commas, other commas are considered part of the email.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice and elegant short method that will do what you ask using a regular expression:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetEmails(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) yield break;
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"[^\s<]+@[^\s,>]+");
    foreach (Match match in matches) yield return match.Value;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
string str = "Last, First <name@domain.com>, name@domain.com, First Last <name@domain.com>, \"First Last\" <name@domain.com>, \"Last, First\" <name@domain.com>";
IEnumerable<string> emails = GetEmails(str);
```

Please note that this regular expression **does not validate the email addresses**, for instance, the email `1@h` will be considered valid and you will get it as a match.

Creating such a regex validator would be a difficult job and probably not the best option.

For retrieving purposes, I think it is the ideal tool.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution only returns the email addresses and the names are required as well. ;-) Agreed re validation. Approach being taken here is to new MailAddress() as that will take care of most of the validation elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly elegant, but try this:

```
        private static IEnumerable<string> GetEntries(string str)
        {
            List<string> entries = new List<string>();
            StringBuilder entry = new StringBuilder();
            while (str.Length > 0)
            {
                char ch = str[0];
                //If the first character on the string is a comma, and the entry already contains na '@'
                //Add this entry to the entries list and clear the temporary entry item.
                if (ch == ',' && entry.ToString().Contains("@"))
                {
                    entries.Add(entry.ToString());
                    entry.Clear();
                }
                //Just add the chacacter to the temporary entry item, otherwise.
                else
                {
                    entry.Append(ch);
                }
                str = str.Remove(0, 1);
            }
            //Add the last entry, which is still in the buffer because it doesn't end with a ',' character.
            entries.Add(entry.ToString());
            return entries;
        }
```

It will Split entries by comma, but only those entries which contains an '@' character before the ',' character.

You would call it like this:

```
string str = "Last, First <name@domain.com>, name@domain.com, First Last <name@domain.com>, \"First Last\" <name@domain.com>, \"Last, First\" <name@domain.com>";
var entries = GetEntries(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

shortest method would be:

```
        string str = "Last, First <name1@domain.com>, name2@domain.com, First Last <name3@domain.com>, \"First Last\" <name4@domain.com>, \"Last, First\" <name5@domain.com>";
        string[] separators = new string[] { "com>,","com,","com>","com"};
    var outputEmail = str.Split(separators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(s=>s.Contains("@")).Select(s=>{return s.Contains('<') ? (s+"com>").Trim() : (s+"com").Trim();});
        foreach (var email in outputEmail)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(email);
        }
```

Comment: Not shortest, mine is one line shorter :P

Comment: It's almost the same. you have mentioned your regex in one line while I defined my variable for that. It can be done in same line as well. But regex sometimes is little confusing, so I go this way

Comment: That's right, you can simplify it. I guess this is a tie!

Comment: Well short or not it does not actually return what is required as it only returns the email addresses - names are required as well. ;-) See https://dotnetfiddle.net/jeX6iQ

Comment: try again :). This time it fetches the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex.Split` with `@"(?<=@\S*)\s+` - it splits on a space (or spaces) preceded by a word containing `@`:

```
string str = "Last, First <name@domain.com>, name@domain.com, First Last <name@domain.com>,  \"First Last\" <name@domain.com>, \"Last, First\" <name@domain.com>";

string[] arr = Regex.Split(str, @"(?<=@\S*)\s+");

foreach (var s in arr)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

output:

```
Last, First <name@domain.com>,
name@domain.com,
First Last <name@domain.com>,
"First Last" <name@domain.com>,
"Last, First" <name@domain.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that handles a few more edge cases and has fewer allocations:

```
public static List<string> ExtractEmailAddresses(string text)
{
    var items = new List<string>();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return items;
    }

    int start = 0;
    bool foundAt = false;
    int comment = 0;

    for (int i = start; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (text[i])
        {
            case '@':
                if (comment == 0) { foundAt = true; }
                break;
            case '(':
                comment++;
                break;
            case ')':
                comment--;
                break;
            case ',':
                HandleLastBlock(i);
                break;
        }
    }

    HandleLastBlock(text.Length);

    return items;

    void HandleLastBlock(int end)
    {
        if (comment == 0 && foundAt && start < end - 1)
        {
            var email = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(text.Substring(start, end - start));
            items.Add(email.Address);
            start = end + 1;
            foundAt = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UserEmails?.Split(';',',',' ','\n','\t').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
```